# Hide implementation details via internal pointer

Tags: c++, pimpl-idiom

I have following third-party class(just wrapper around some pointer):

```
// a.h
class AImpl;
class A
{
    AImpl*   pImpl;

public:
    A(): pImpl(0) {}
    A(AImpl* ptr): pImpl(ptr) {}
    ...
    AImpl* getImpl() const { return pImpl; }
    ...
    void someMethodOfA();
};
```

I want to modify `A`'s interface: disable some methods, add some new, while hiding its implementation details. I decided to do following:

```
// new_a.h
class AImpl;
class A;

class NewA
{
    AImpl*   pImpl;

public:
    NewA( const A& a );
    ...
    void newMethodOfA();
    ...
};

//new_a.cpp
#include "a.h"
NewA::NewA( const A& a ): pImpl( a.getImpl() ) {}
...
void NewA::newMethodOfA()
{
    A( pImpl ).someMethodOfA();
}
...
```

Is it ok to do so? Maybe there is better solution? I want to change `A` interface because it doesn't fit my needs and don't want to keep it in my own code.

Comment: It is important here if "A" has got virtual member functions, in that case you can derive from A and create your own set of member function, and if necessary call some from Base class.

Comment: @CyberGuy No, `A` has no virtual functions. It wasn't designed to be polymorphic.

Comment: What implementation are you trying to hide?. Your `pImpl` is effectively `public`.

Comment: @indeterminatelysequenced I am trying to hide `A` implementation. `NewA::pImpl` is private by default. I don't want to allocate `A` and hold `A* pImpl`, because it's already a wrapper around some pointer (`AImpl`)

Comment: Then your `class A` is extra and unneeded. Get rid of it & add `someMethodOfA()` to `NewA`. Why would you do `pImpl( a.getImpl() )` followed by `A( pImpl ).someMethodOfA();` !

Comment: As a suggestion, it seems that you wanna do the same as proposed by adapter pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern

Comment: @indeterminatelysequenced `A` already implements pimpl idiom. I want to provide modified interface of `A` so users of `NewA` won't know anything about `A` and `AImpl` ( it will be forward declared ). I create temporary `A` object in implementation of `NewA`, using internal pointer of `A`.

Comment: Putting PIMPL on top of PIMPL? Instead I suggest you just smile and go with SIMPL

Comment: You could just hold a value of type A. Which would be an implementation of the adapter pattern.

Comment: @indeterminatelysequenced This is the thing i want to avoid :) I don't want to have `a.h` included in users of `NewA`, it should hide all details of `A` inside it. And I don't want to create `A` objects on heap.

Answer (score 1):

In a comment you say that

> I don't want to allocate A and hold A* pImpl, because it's already a wrapper around some pointer (AImpl)

Despite this requirement, you allocate a temporary `A` object in `NewA::newMethodOfA()`. In what way is this supposed to be better than allocating `A` once and just re-use it? Your solution is not good because 1) you create a new temporary `A` over and over again, and 2) you force the users of `NewA` to provide an instance of `A` instead of just creating one yourself.

I suggest you bite the bullet and just make a proper "PIMPL on top of PIMPL" implementation (as Captain Obvlious puts it):

```
// new_a.h
class A;

class NewA
{
    A* pImpl;

public:
    NewA();
    ~NewA();

    void newMethodOfA();
};

//new_a.cpp
#include "a.h"
NewA::NewA() : pImpl( new A() ) {}
NewA::~NewA() { delete pImpl; }

void NewA::newMethodOfA()
{
    pImpl->someMethodOfA();
}
```

This meets all your other requirements:

1. You don't want to have `a.h` included in `new_a.h`
2. You want to provide a modified interface of `A` so users of `NewA` won't know anything about `A` and `AImpl`
3. You want to hide the implementation of `A`

The only thing that doesn't quite meet up is that in the code you show the default constructor of `A` initializes its `pImpl` member to 0 - this is weird! Since when is the user of a PIMPL class required to provide the object that is wrapped by the PIMPL class? Cf. Wikipedia's [Opaque Pointer article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opaque_pointer).

Comment: `A` object actually is a node of some tree, so there will be a lot of such objects created around. I don't want to allocate each of them on heap because it can hit performance. All real stuff is in `AImpl`. I suppose that creating temporary object on stack for this purpose is faster than dynamically allocate it, but i can be wrong.

Comment: I found [Fast Pimpl Idiom](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/028.htm) that seems to be the best solution, but in this particular case as far as `A` exposes pointer to internal implementation, i think it will be easier to just use it...